# Что такое атрибуты в C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++-faq

Начиная со стандарта [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) в языке появились так называемые "атрибуты", что это такое и зачем они нужны?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[Атрибуты](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr) позволяют задавать дополнительную информацию для различных конструкций языка, таких как типы, переменные, имена, блоки и единицы трансляции. Данная информация в частности может быть использована компилятором для генерации более эффективного кода и предоставления (или наоборот, подавления) предупреждающих сообщений пользователю на уровне конкретных участков кода, а не целой программы или компилируемого файла, как это обеспечивается ключами компиляции.

Атрибуты появились в [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) и впоследствии были несколько расширены. На данный момент существуют следующие стандартные атрибуты:

- `assume`
- `carries_dependency`
- `deprecated`
- `fallthrough`
- `likely` и `unlikely`
- `maybe_unused`
- `nodiscard`
- `noreturn`
- `no_unique_address`

Набор атрибутов может быть расширен каждой конкретной реализацией компилятора, в таком случае его поведение будет описываться отдельно. Неизвестный атрибут будет проигнорирован, но может быть выведено предупреждающее сообщение.

Атрибут всегда обрамляется двойными квадратными скобками:

```
[[атрибут]]
```

---

Пойдём по порядку:

### `[[assume]]`

Атрибут (доступен начиная с [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23)) применяется к пустой операции `;`. Это интерпретируется как предположение. Аргумент атрибута обязан присутствовать и иметь форму `(условное_выражение)`. Тип выражения интерпретируется как `bool`, а само выражение не является вычисляемым, т.е. не меняет состояние программы. Если результат выражения интерпретируется как `true`, то предположение не имеет эффекта, в противном случае - [поведение не определено](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/900292/176217). Предположение позволяет компилятору анализировать форму выражения и использовать этот результат для целей оптимизации программы, но это не является обязательным и может быть проигнорировано.

```
int divide_by_32(int x) {
  [[assume(x >= 0)]];
  return x/32;           // Машинные инструкции, сгенерированные для деления 
                         // могут пропустить обработку отрицательных чисел
}
int f(int y) {
  [[assume(++y == 43)]]; // `y` не будет увеличен,
  return y;              // выражение может быть заменено на return 42;
}
```

### `[[carries_dependency]]`

Данный атрибут не изменяет смысл программы, но может приводить к генерации более эффективного кода. Атрибут может применяться как к целой функции, так и к её параметрам. Может быть полезен на системах со слабо упорядоченной архитектурой при передаче значения между вычислительными потоками. Самый сложный для понимания атрибут :) Поэтому за дополнительной информацией - на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6411270/).

### `[[deprecated]]`

Позволяет отметить сущность устаревшей или небезопасной, но тем не менее пока ещё разрешённой к использованию. Может применяться к объявлению класса, typedef-имени, переменной, нестатическому члену данных, функции, пространству имён, перечислению, элементу перечисления или специализации шаблона. Атрибут может быть снабжен аргументом, заданным строковым литералом. Например:

```
[[deprecated("используйте функцию g()")]]
void f();
```

Текстовое сообщение будет использовано как подсказка при выводе соответствующего предупреждения.

### `[[fallthrough]]`

Данный атрибут применяется к пустой операции, т.е. `;`. Может быть использован только внутри `switch` для уведомления компилятора о задуманном программистом "проваливании" цепочки действий из одной ветки `case` в другую. Атрибут позволяет подавлять предупреждение компилятора, которое он может выдать, если между метками `case` не будет обнаружен оператор `break`. Часто отсутствие `break` может быть банальной ошибкой, возникшей по невнимательности. Пример:

```
switch (i)
{
    case 1:
       ... 
       [[fallthrough]]; 
    case 2:
       ...
}
```

### `[[likely]]` и `[[unlikely]]`

Атрибуты могут быть добавлены к меткам `case` или операторам (*statement*) для подсказки компилятору, что тот или иной участок кода ожидается наиболее вероятным (*likely*) или, наоборот, менее вероятным (*unlikely*) при выполнении программы. Пример:

```
void g(int);
int f(int n) {
  if (n > 5) [[unlikely]] {     // n > 5 маловероятная ветка
    g(0);
    return n * 2 + 1;
  }

  switch (n) {
  case 1:
    g(1);
    [[fallthrough]];

  [[likely]] case 2:            // n == 2 более вероятное значение
    g(2);                       // нежели любое другое n
    break;
  }
  return 3;
}
```

### `[[maybe_unused]]`

Используется для уведомления компилятора о том, что сущность может быть не использована в программе и следует подавлять соответствующее предупреждение. Может применяться к объявлению класса, typedef-имени, переменной, нестатическому члену данных, функции, пространству имён, перечислению или элементу перечисления. Атрибут может быть полезен при наличии отладочного кода, который не будет включён в бинарник при сборке в release режиме. Пример:

```
[[maybe_unused]] void f([[maybe_unused]] bool thing1,
                        [[maybe_unused]] bool thing2) {
  [[maybe_unused]] bool b = thing1 && thing2;
  assert(b);
}
```

Ранее приходилось использовать приведение к `void` для подавления возможных предупреждений.

### `[[nodiscard]]`

Указывает на обязательность использования результата при возврате из функции. Может быть применим как к типу (при объявлении класса или перечисления), так и непосредственно к возвращаемому типу функции. Пример:

```
[[nodiscard]]
int f() { return 42; }
...
f(); // сообщение о том, что результат функции не использован
```

Явное приведение результата к `void` подавляет действие атрибута:

```
static_cast<void>(f()); // нет предупреждения о не использованном результате
```

Альтернативно можно использовать присваивание `std::ignore`:

```
#include <tuple>
std::ignore = f(); // нет предупреждения о не использованном результате
```

Начиная с C++20 можно использовать дополнительный строковый литерал для пояснения причины наличия атрибута по аналогии с атрибутом `[[deprecated]]`.

### `[[noreturn]]`

Говорит о том, что функция не возвращает управление. Может быть применим к объявлению функции. Актуально для функций, которые заканчивают свою работу выкидыванием исключения, выполняют вечный цикл или прерывают выполнение всей программы. Пример:

```
[[noreturn]] 
void f() {
    throw "error";
}
```

Если функция, помеченная атрибутом `[[noreturn]]`, возвращает управление на одной из веток выполнения, то это приводит к неопределённому поведению.

### `[[no_unique_address]]`

Указывает на то, что нестатический член данных класса является потенциально-перекрываемым (*potentially-overlapping*) подобъектом (не может применяться к битовым полям). Это значит что член может иметь общий адрес с другим нестатическим членом данных этого или базового класса, а заполнители, которые обычно вставляются в конец объекта, могут быть использованы для хранения других членов. Пример:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value,
typename Hash, typename Pred, typename Allocator>
class hash_map {
  [[no_unique_address]] Hash hasher;
  [[no_unique_address]] Pred pred;
  [[no_unique_address]] Allocator alloc;
  Bucket *buckets;
// ...
public:
// ...
};
```

Здесь `hasher`, `pred` и `alloc` могут иметь тот же адрес, что и `buckets`, если соответствующие им типы окажутся пустыми.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что с помощью `[[no_unique_address]]` можно довольно легко добиться экономии памяти? Насколько это эффективно в сравнении с использованием объединений?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия `[[no_unique_address]]` это для пустых типов, в которых нет членов-данных. А объединения `union` для разделения памяти между объектами, которые хранят данные.

Comment: Разве это не должно быть самим собой разумеющимся? Я сейчас проверил: пустые типы по умолчанию заполняются нулями, причём количество этих нулей зависит от длины других членов класса. Идиотизм какой-то.