# Стандартный аналог __attribute__ ((constructor))

Tags: c++, c++14

Существует ли стандартный аналог конструкции gcc:

```
__attribute__ ((constructor))
```

Я понимаю, что всегда можно написать:

```
 static bool ini_once = ( do_somthing(), true );
```

, но хотелось бы минимизировать работу при портировании кода с gcc на стандарт С++11/С++14 и не изобретать лишних переменных.

Answer (score 0):

Этот атрибут в первую очередь служит для того, чтобы привнести динамическую инициализацию (в стиле С++) в языки, в которых динамическая инициализация не поддерживается, то есть в С.

В С++ любая динамическая инициализация - это и есть аналог. Вы как раз сами и привели абстрактный пример. Можно так, а можно поместить эти действия в конструктор глобального объекта.

Comment: Решение с созданием дополнительной переменной (а тем более класса), мне не нравится из-за засорения пространства имен. `__attribute__((constructor))` позволяет выполнить инициализацию анонимно чего мне и хочется..

Comment: @Chorkov Используйте лямбды

Comment: @Chorkov namespace{
auto unused = [](){ std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; return 0;}();
}

Comment: @vegorov Так глобальное пространство имен все равно засоряется, потому что снаружи безымянного namespace, ЕМНИП,  автоматически ставится `using namespace …;`.

Comment: Можно еще `[[maybe_unused]]` дописать, чтобы не было предупреждения о неиспользуемой переменной.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat это с с++11 появилось ? или с c++14? Это в стандарте языка или фича компилятора конкретного ?

Comment: @vegorov, C++17

Comment: @HolyBlackCat просто это неименованое пространство надо держать в `cpp` файле, а не в заголовочном

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ага, вот почему я ещё не знаю эту фичу =)

Comment: @vegorov про [атрибуты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662431/176217).