# Можно ли использовать атрибуты в параметрах main?

Tags: c++, атрибуты, main

Можно ли использовать атрибуты в параметрах функции `main`?

В стандарте указаны только 2 возможные формы без атрибутов, но дело в том, что у меня в программе не используется `argc` параметр и я хотел бы пометить его как `maybe_unused`, чтобы не выдавало предупреждения постоянно:

```
int main([[maybe_unused]] int argc, char* argv[]);
```

Ошибок код не выдает, но легально ли так делать?

Comment: можно конечно, всего означает, что аргумент может быть не использован

Comment: Не очень понятно, как вы будете использовать `argv`, если не знаете их кол-во, заданное в `argc`. Вероятно, вам просто нужно использовать вариант `main` без параметров. Кстати, почитать про атрибуты можно [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662431/176217).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти атрибуты - это отключение соответствующих warning у компилятора, они не влияют на итоговый код.

Следовательно, в свете их применения, нет разницы, в каком месте их применять.

Альтернативно, можно убрать у параметра имя. Это как раз явно - нет имени, значит, и пользоваться нельзя. Понадобится воспользоваться - вернете имя на место.

```
 int main(int, char*[]);
```

Comment: "Да, так можно делать" - можно подтверждение?

Comment: а для чего точная ясность  использует или не использует? Зачем все тело функции просматривать. Используется или нет, в данном случаи не важно, важно то, что разрешено не использовать.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вариант `int main(int, char*[]);` точно разрешён, а вот с аттрибутом непонятно

Comment: почему не понятно? Очень даже понятно.  В указанном вами варианте(старый прием) придется добавлять имя, если вдруг понадобился, а  с атрибутом(современный подход) просто используйте или не используйте

Comment: @ARHovsepyan можно подтверждение, что в параметрах main могут быть аттрибуты?

Comment: Подтверждением является его предназначение.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17#%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2_%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%91%D0%BD_%D0%B8_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0

Comment: @ARHovsepyan там не сказано, что аттрибуты можно использовать в main.

Comment: @wall Эти атрибуты - это отключение соответствующих warning у компилятора, они не влияют на итоговый код.

Comment: @gbg почему [в объявлении функции](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) явно указан список аттрибутов, а [у main](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) - нет?

Comment: @wall Потому что там есть третий пункт про implementation defined, и атрибуты эти - тоже implementation defined

Comment: @gbg тогда нельзя использовать кроссплатформенно, получается