# Атрибут nodiscard

Tags: c++, атрибуты, nodiscard

Для примера написал такой класс:

```cpp
class TestClass {
public:
    char v(const std::string& str) const {
        return str[0];
    }
};
```

Компилятор хочет, чтобы я пометил функцию `v` атрибутом `[[nodiscard]]`:
`Clang-Tidy: Function 'v' should be marked [[nodiscard]]`.
Почему? Какие последствия будут в зависимости от того, помечу я её или нет?

Comment: а можно узнать, что это за компилятор и послушать его версию событий?

Comment: @Fat-Zer я неправильно выразился. Не компилятор, а CLion. Пишет: `Clang-Tidy: Function 'v' should be marked [[nodiscard]]`.

Comment: а флаги? на [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/e5Wxdq)'е ни как не ругается...

Comment: вероятно, просто видит, что у функции нет ни каких побочных эффектов и решает, что её значение всегда должно использоваться, дабы избежать ошибок при случайном удалении `foo=` в `foo=tc.v("bar");`

Comment: нуда, примерно так и есть, критерии чтобы он начал рекомендовать см. здесь: https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize-use-nodiscard.html

Comment: @Fat-Zer ну и хорошо. Я думал, вдруг это что-то важное. Спасибо.

Comment: @Fat-Zer хорошо бы оформить ответом.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия по аттрибутам можете ещё [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/662432/176217) почитать.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, в ближайшее время у меня похоже не дойдут руки... я не против, если кто-то другой оформит...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На основании упомянутой в комментарии [ссылки](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize-use-nodiscard.html) clang-tidy (используемый в CLion) предлагает добавить атрибут `[[nodiscard]]` к функции, т.к. функция подходит под перечисленный список условий. Суть условий в том, что видимое поведение функции может быть доступно только через возвращаемый результат. Если его проигнорировать, то такая функция будет выглядеть бесполезной. Чтобы этого избежать как раз существует упомянутый атрибут.

Подробнее о существующих атрибутах C++ можно почитать [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662431/176217).