# Объявление указателей с++

Tags: c++, указатели, типы-данных, объявление

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему символ `*` при объявлении указателей должен стоять рядом с каждым идентификатором? Разве `int*` нельзя считать как "отдельный" тип?

Comment: Нет такого типа -- `int *`. `*` это атрибут имени переменной, она говорит, что эта переменная указатель

Comment: @avp, просто когда мы берем приведение типов, то можем увидеть такую конструкцию `(int*)a` и это очень похоже на отдельный тип

Comment: Логично (но что еще, не обремененное множеством букв, можно было придумать? Вообще, imho любой нормальный для восприятия язык будет контекстнозависимым)

Comment: У меня есть впечатление, что можно "у себя в голове" спокойно считать int* отдельным типом. И это, как мне кажется, ничему не будет мешать. Навскидку я не могу придумать примеров, когда такое "мысленное упрощение" не будет работать. ну, правда, при объявлении нескольких переменных в одном объявлении появляется "исключение из этого мысленного правила"

Comment: @avp, а где можно почитать про эти самые атрибуты, просто в результатах поиска у меня [такие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662431/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-c). И там не совсем та информация которая мне нужна(

Comment: `int *` - это отдельный тип, объявлять указатели следует по одному за раз.

Comment: Нет такого термина, "атрибут имени переменной". `int *` - это тип.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, насчет атрибута имени переменной. Я тут читал пункт `Declarators` в стандарте и там было написано: `ptr-operator:
* attribute-specifier-seq opt cv-qualifier-seqopt
& attribute-specifier-seq opt
&& attribute-specifier-seq opt`, а по запросу про этот самый `attribute-specifier-seq` мне выдает [это](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes). И я что-то запутался что есть что.

Comment: Или `*` не относится к этому `attribute-specifier-seq`?

Comment: @n1kzzz Ссылка правильная. Эта запись означает, что справа от звездочки может стоять `[[...]]` (attribute-specifier-seq). Звездочка - не часть attribute-specifier-seq, конечно. Они же рядом написаны. Если бы звездочка была его частью, то она была бы написата [тут](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.grammar#nt:attribute-specifier-seq).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> почему символ * при объявлении указателей должен стоять рядом с каждым идентификатором

Потому что грамматику такую сделали. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Объявления имеют вид (упрощенно):

```
decl-specifier-seq declarator, declarator, ..., declarator
```

Один [декларатор](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl.general#nt:declarator) создает одну переменную. В центре него - имя переменной, а вокруг имени могут (но не обязаны) быть `*`, `&`, `[...]`, `(...)` и т. д.

Все остальное попадает в [decl-specifier-seq](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.general#nt:decl-specifier-seq) (в вашем случае это `int`).

Тип каждой переменной определяется по общему для всех переменных decl-specifier-seq, и плюс по информации из декларатора этой конкретной переменной.

Например в `int *a, b;`:

- decl-specifier-seq - это `int`
- `*a` - первый декларатор
- `b` - второй декларатор

Так что `*`, как часть декларатора, влияет только на свой декларатор. А `int`, как часть decl-specifier-seq, влияет на обе переменные.

Comment: А есть ли свое название у этих символов, которые объявляют массив или указатель и т. д. Допустим про имя переменной мы модем сказать что это идентификатор, а как тогда правильно назвать эту часть декларатора?

Comment: @n1kzzz Почитал первую ссылку из ответа, и вижу, что `*`, `&`, `&&`, и `Класс::*` называются *ptr-operator*. Но это настолько хитрое название, что если вы кому-то их так назовете, вас не поймут. `[...]`, судя по той же ссылке, никак не называются.

Answer (score 3):

> Разве int* нельзя считать как "отдельный" тип?

Почему нельзя? Можно. *Если сделать его типом*. Например -

```
typedef int * pint;

pint a, b, c;
```

А иначе - как компилятору понять, что именно вы хотите в объявлении `int * a, b;`? Вот он и придерживается стандарта :)

Comment: эх, недосмотрели разработчики си... было бы интересно, если `int* a,b;` - это два указателя. а `int *a, b;` - это указатель и число.... сколько бы новых вопросов было бы...

Comment: @KoVadim Да-да, а еще отступы чтобы имели значение... И сразу популярность языка взлетит до небес :)

Comment: не нужно мне тут питоном обмазывать.