# Type conversion to void (not to void*)

Tags: c++, type-conversion

В описании к [named requirement InputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) в таблице приведено в пример выражение (`(void)i++`), на которое я никогда ранее не натыкался. В чём смысл каста к `void` и почему это вообще валидно?

Comment: В документации это выражение означает что должен быть определён постинкремент с любым возвращаемым типом.

Comment: В коде иногда выражение приводят к `void` чтобы линтер или компилятор не ругался на неиспользованное значение. Например `printf` без `(void)` заставит линтер ругаться ("надо проверить что всё что напечатано - напечатано!"). А нам не хочется следовать этим строгостям: `(void)printf(...)`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, лучше бы написали просто `T`. Для плюсов это привычнее выглядит)

Comment: Каст к `void` означает вычислить выражение, а результирующее значение просто отбросить, [expr.static.cast/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#6). Оба инкремента `++i` и `i++` делают две вещи: 1) возвращают некоторое значение, 2) изменяют внутреннее состояние итератора. То что выражение `(void)i++` эквивалентно выражению `(void)++i` — это такой изощрённый способ сказать, что они оба одинаковым образом изменяют внутреннее состояние итератора, но возвращаемые значения могут отличаться.

Comment: `лучше бы написали просто T` Если написать, что 1) `++i` возвращает `It&`, 2) `i++` возвращает `T`, 3) `i++` эквивалентен `++i`, то тогда выходит, что `T` должен совпадать с `It&`, а это не так.

Comment: В коде же использование каста к `void` может применяться для подавления предупреждений компилятора при использовании атрибута [nodiscard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard), а также для подавления вызова перегруженной версии оператора запятая вместо встроенной (см.: [Why does std::transform and similar cast the 'for' loop increment to (void)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38357089)).

Comment: @wololo, `*++iter` точно будет отличаться от `*iter++`. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: @megorit, "просто T" требует вполне определённую сигнатуру. `(void)` говорит "возвращайте что хотите, меня интересует только побочный эффект". Тут свободы больше.

Comment: @wololo может оформите ответом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Канонический оператор постинкремента в выражении `i++` выполняет следующие действия:

1. запомнить текущее значение `i`
2. увеличить `i` на "единицу" (с учётом типа переменной)
3. вернуть прежнее значение `i` до увеличения

Причём возврат прежнего значения - это именно фишка пост-версии оператора. Если нет необходимости получать старое значение, а просто "шагнуть вперёд", то более правильным вариантом будет использование преинкремента. Соответственно, если результат работы постинкремента никак не использован в коде, то компилятор логично может предположить, что в коде допущена ошибка и выдать соответствующее предупреждение. Явно такая необходимость использования возвращаемого значения может быть указана с помощью [атрибута](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/662431/176217) `[[nodiscard]]`. А для подавления подобных предупреждений как раз и используется приведение к `void`. Т.е. этим мы сообщаем компилятору, что несмотря на использование постинкремента, возвращаемое значение нас не интересует.

В упомянутой вами таблице добавление `(void)` позволяет показать связь между выражениями `i++` и `++i`. То есть, если возвращаемые значения игнорируются, их действия эквиваленты, иначе они, конечно же, будут отличаться.

Comment: `for (int idx = 0; idx < size; ++idx) {}` и `for (int idx = 0; idx < size; idx++) {}` фактически ничем отличаться не будут, т.к. ненаблюдаемое поведение, и, соответственно, оптимизация.

Comment: @megorit для `int` не будут, а для какого-нибудь класса - будут. Хотя бы даже для итераторов.

Comment: Да, наверно, хотя для STL может быть предусмотрели.