# Документирование кода метками

Tags: c++, c, документация, label, комментарии

Насколько хорошей практикой является документирование кода метками? В каких ситуациях стоит её использовать?

К примеру, если надо акцентировать внимание в алгоритме:

```
special_case:
if (cond) {
  ...
  return true;
}

usual_path: 
return false;
```

Из плюсов:

1. меньше символов;
2. можно написать в начале строки перед кодом с более простым синтаксисом, чем `/* */`.

Из минусов:

1. только короткие фразы;
2. предупреждения компиляторов.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: О том, что использование goto - плохая практика, написано уже столько... ¿Откуда вообще могла вылезти идея использовать метки для документирования?

Comment: @user7860670 в вопросе не идёт речь об использовании `goto`

Comment: ¿т.е. как это, не идет? `special_case:` - ¿это разве не метка для goto?

Comment: Как по мне — идея, гм... очень спорная... и это чтоб не выражаться матом :)

Comment: если вместо cond использовать имя is_special_case, то уже метка не нужна. И так далее. Если нужно выделить блок - возможно, этот код нужно вынести в отдельную функцию? Если же и это невозможно - используйте комментарии с метками. Например, `//! --- special case ----`

Comment: @user7860670 речь идёт об использовании меток как документации кода, а не про использование `goto` для них

Comment: А эти метки нельзя просто так использовать без goto. Это будет порождать диагностики при сборке C4102 / Wunused-label

Comment: @user7860670 добавил в минусы, но этот варнинг можно отключить, если что

Comment: @user7860670 интересно узнать про сохранение названий меток в бинарях в отличие от комментариев...

Comment: не сохраняются, не переживайте.

Comment: @KoVadim много символов в `//! --- special case ----` по сравнению с меткой

Comment: ну так Вы же хотите, что бы "оно бросалось в глаза". Но у меток есть большущий минус - Вам нужно будет всем объяснять, зачем это нужно.

Comment: Оба ваших плюса сводятся по сути к экономии пары байт. Пара экранирующих символов намного меньше, чем количество символов в самом комментарии и погоды вообще не делает.

Comment: В некоторых редакторах в самом деле будет выделяться своим другим цветом. Но, уж больно сбивающе для неподготовленного читателя, который может потратить немало времени, выясняя, *откуда сюда переходят?*

Comment: @KoVadim, уверены? А если бинарный файл с DWARF’ом?

Comment: Если оставить отладочную информацию, то тут много чего может быть. Тут люди все юмор понимают, но strip для релизов делают

Answer (score 2):

Довольно неожиданное предложение по использованию меток и как уже было упомянуто, такое действие будет порождать предупреждения компилятора со всеми вытекающими. Его придётся подавлять, чтобы не отвлекало внимание от других проблем, или вовсе не блокировало сборку при наличии опции "treat warning as an error". Но в таком случае этот тип предупреждений (пусть и редкий в наши дни) можно пропустить в другом коде, где "метки используются как метки, а не альтернатива комментариям".

Вообще, в современном C++ для указания на наиболее вероятную ветвь ветвления стоит использовать [атрибуты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/662432/176217) `[[likely]]`, `[[unlikely]]`. Атрибуты не только могут быть подспорьем документированию кода, но и дадут подсказку компилятору, чтобы сделать код более эффективным.

```
if (cond) [[unlikely]] {
  ...
  return true;
}

return false;
```